# Is there a way to override an existing React component method?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using a third-party React class component (e.g. `SomeComponent`) with some method. This method raises an exception in my case, and I'd like to override it to apply a fix.

Something like that:

```
export class MyComponent extends SomeComponent {
    //...
    someBuggyMethod () {
        doFix();
    }
}
```

I know that inheritance is an anti-pattern in React. Is there a good way to do it differently?

Comment: What's the problem with doing inheritance in this case?

Comment: As React documentation says, it is not a recommended way, that's all: https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html

Comment: Of what nature is your fix? Have you considered modifying the class at runtime? `ClasName.functionName = function(...) {....}` ?

Comment: Thank you guys, I recognized that problem in the third-party lib is deeper, and it cannot be solved by simple overriding.